# Why is System.Threading.tasks.Extensions after compiling not found? While in debug mode there is no problem

Tags: c#

During testing of the compiled app build I encounter the exception which can be seen in the picture.

[image]

First I thought it had something to do with the method I wrote, where the exception occurs. But after reading some topics on this forum, I doubt this is the problem.

There seems to be a version mismatch of version of System.Threading.tasks.Extensions. In the exeption i can see that version 4.2.0.1 is being loaded.
But in i can see in my *.sln file that i have added:
.

I have taken a look at the NuGet extensions and form there I don't seem to be able to downgrade to the requested version.
Also I have read a couple of topics to see if someone else encountered the same problem. They seem similar but I am not sure.
I need some advise on the best way to a possible solution and I'm to new at programming to see if the problems I have read in the other topics are indeed similar.

Comment: If you inspect and compare the files in the /debug and the /release folders, is the DLL in one but not the other? Or are there different versions in the folders?

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your answer. It made  me rethink over all the files I had to include in the plugin I am building. Due to my inexperience I did not include all the files in the folder and this caused the problem.